# AppImage application bundle

Tags: appimage

I have a new pc with linux ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installed. Linux is new to me so I am learning as I go. I am trying to install some accounting software via an appimage file, however i receive an error as follows:

Could Not Display "Manager-linux-x64.AppImage"
There is no application installed for "AppImage application bundle" files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file?

I have ticked the permissions to allow executing file as a program but it doesn't do anything when trying to open. Any recommendations on what I can do to install this file? The recommended software has negative reviews so I would prefer not to install that one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Appimage files need to be set as executable.  `chmod +x Manager-linux-x64.AppImage` and they run in their own space.

Comment: yes i have set this to allow executing file as a program. However it still doesn't open. Anything else I need to do?

Comment: https://appimage.org/ is what they are.  Maybe you need to do the `chmod a+x filename.appimage` and it should work.  There should not be any associated files to open it, and if it is asking then it might be a bad download or just a bad file.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the info. Looks like my novice skills aren't going to get it working and I'll have to get outside help. Appreciate you taking to time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Appimages require the FUSE filesystem to run.  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS doesn't include FUSE by default.  But once you install it, the Appimage will work just fine.

Install instructions may be found [here](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE) - be sure to pay attention to the fact that in 22.04 you use `libfuse2` rather than `fuse`.

In future: this info (and the link) may be found by getting into a terminal and executing your Appimage from there: in that case you will see the log messages explaining that FUSE is not installed.  For example:

```
% ./sample-app 
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2

AppImages require FUSE to run. 
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because the file manager was run as root.

Closing all file manager windows and then re-opening allowed me to double-click and run AppImage files.